# Error in my development environment for java webapp

Tags: maven, primefaces, jsf-2, glassfish-5

I am working on a java webapp.

- Glassfish 5.0
- Primefaces 6.0
- JSF 2.1
- JDK 8
- Maven / Eclipse

Normal components like `outputLabel` etc. are working just fine. But some more complex primeface components such as galleria, switch or effect are breaking. Gallery and switch have weird appearances and effects don't seem to work at all.
So I figured something must be wrong with my setup. Some dependency missing or some incompatibility between the versions. Sadly I am to new to web development so I wouldn't know such things.

Here are my maven dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have already stated the problem with the galleria in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241834/primefaces-pgalleria-wont-display-images-separately). Since other components kept breaking on me I didn't even bother asking for help for each of them separately and assumed it must be a problem with my setup.
Does anyone have a clue whats wrong with my setup?

EDIT: this was marked as a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553417/primefaces-css-looknfeel-missing-and-js-uncaught-reference-error-primefaces) by BalusC. Sadly it is not the same problem causing the issue. I just copied the code from [here](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/effect.xhtml) and it did not work. Same for other things like galleria etc. On my effect-page none of the effects trigger. It also looks different than the showcase, see here:
[image]

Comment: This question is no duplicate, see my EDIT for explanation.

Comment: I found out what was missing. I had to change some configurations in my web.xml and my maven dependencies didnt contain what was needed by far. I would post an answer with my changes but i cant, since the topic wrongly still counts as a duplicate